# Deserialization of web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

Im trying to parse JSON into ListView, but its giving me deserialization error.
This is my model - it's same as api's keys:

```
public class Currency
{
    public string Drzava { get; set; }
    public int Sifra_valute { get; set; }
    public string Drzava_iso { get; set; }
    public int Jedinica { get; set; }
    public double Kupovni_tecaj { get; set; }
    public double Srednji_tecaj { get; set; }
    public double Prodajni_tecaj { get; set; }
}
```

This is my list of Currencies:

```
public class CurrencyTable
{
    public List<Currency> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Class for binding with Listview:

```
public class ShowCurrency
{
    static ShowCurrency() {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {

            String rawJSON = 
     webClient.DownloadString("http://api.hnb.hr/tecajn/v2/");
            CurrencyTable currencyTable = 
     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrencyTable>(rawJSON);

        }
    }
    private static List<Currency> currencies;
    public static List<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public static List<Currency> GetCurrencies() {
        return Currencies;
    }
   }
```

And i get error at: CurrencyTable currencyTable = 
         JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawJSON);

this is how api looks like:
http://api.hnb.hr/tecajn/v2

Comment: well what does the rawJSON look like? edit: nevermind, looks like you can view the json at the link you provided

Comment: Please add the JSON to the question.

Comment: your JSON structure does not match the properties of the class you are trying to deserialize it into

Comment: For example, your JSON has a list of objects. Each object in that list has a property called "broj_tecajnice", however this property is not in the Currency class, therefore it cannot be deserialized.

Comment: Use      JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Currency>>(rawJSON);

Comment: should i change properties to strings just to see does it work?

Comment: Don't *link* us the JSON.  **Paste the JSON into the question**.  Your question should contain everything needed to answer it.  Going off-site should not be necessary.

Comment: As the others have noted, if you want to use the container object, you will need an extra pair of {} around the JSON with the list as a property contained in that object, or you need to deserialize it as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web-service response body starts with this text:

```
[{"broj_tecajnice":"85","datum_primjene":"2019-05-...
```

Note how it starts with `[` which means it's returning a JSON array directly as its root object and that it is not returning an object with a member named `Results` (i.e. it is not returning `{ Results: [ {"broj_tecajnice"... }, { ... } ] }`.

Change your code to this:

```
List<Currency> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Currency>>( rawJSON );
CurrencyTable currencyTable = new CurrencyTable()
{
    Results = list
};
```